# Blurry linear gradient stops in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, linear-gradients, gradientstop

If I am using a linear gradient with multiple stops like this:

```
div
{
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 2000px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #383937 0, #001500 35px,
    #ffffff 35px, #b0b0b0 150px, #ffffff 150px, #ffffff 100%);
}
```

**Firefox**
Problem free.

**Chrome**
The transitions between gradient colors are blurry.
I am reusing a position to define a new color, so on position 35, the color goes from #001500 to #ffffff instantly (or at least should). The blurryness between gradient stops increases if the div is taller.

**IE**
There is some blurryness like in chrome, but less extreme. Like in Chrome, the blurryness increases if the div is made higher.

http://jsfiddle.net/cyq7grdr/5/

The gradient in firefox:

[image: gradient in firefox]

The gradient in chrome:

[image: gradient in chrome]

The gradient in chrome when the div is less tall (1000px instead of 2000px):

[image]

## edit

It seems like this is fixed in chrome, but introduced in firefox. If anyone can confirm this, I would be happy.

Comment: Related: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=140208

Comment: Is there some workaround? Seems like this will not be fixed anytime soon...

Comment: I absolutely hate saying this... but use an image. It only has to be 1px wide with `repeat-x`.

Comment: Will not stretch correctly if the last gradient is using two colors instead of #fffff to #fffff like in this case, bad example!

Comment: I am talking about vertical stretching (to 100%)

Comment: Maybe I can combine multiple backgrounds with images to have the desired stretching

Comment: Clarification, when I say stretch I refer to having a header with a specified height, then after that having a page with a linear gradient not having the same start and end color, being up to 100% of the page height.

Comment: Using a background image would cause the resizing of the page to alter the height of the "header" as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not a fix to the problem, just a workaround… you can use multiple gradients as multiple backgrounds of a small enough size as to not trigger the problem (< ~300px seems to do it). Combine with `background-size` and `background-position` and you get something that is ugly, but works:

```
background-image:
    linear-gradient(to bottom, #383937 0, #001500 35px, #ffffff 35px, #b0b0b0 150px),
    linear-gradient(to bottom, #963 0, #abc 150px);
background-size:
    100px 150px,
    100px 150px;
background-position:
    0 0,
    0 150px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cyq7grdr/11/) for demo.

Answer (score 2):

I just had this requirement in a project and solved it this way:

Let's say we want the color change to be 50%.

- We must place the gradient of the first color from 0% to 51%.
- And the gradient of the next color from 50% to 100%.

In this way they overlap and create a cut color effect.

```css
.background-overlap {
  background: rgb(97, 0, 189);
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(46, 49, 49, 1) 0%,  rgba(46, 49, 49, 1) 51%, rgba(232, 232, 232, 1) 50%, rgba(232, 232, 232, 1) 100%);
}

.mydiv {
  height: 90vh;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="background-overlap mydiv"></div>
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Functioning workaround for this issue: Just use multiple linear brackgrounds for the background (this is trivially possible with CSS 3) and use `transparent` background color as an empty placeholder for the other linear background being visible through:

```css
background: 
    linear-gradient(to right, 
      green 10%, 
      yellowgreen 10%, yellowgreen 20%, 
      yellow 20%, yellow 30%, 
      orange 30%, orange 40%, 
      red 40%, red 50%, 
      grey 50%, grey 60%,
      blue 60%, blue 70%,
      transparent 70%
    ),
    linear-gradient(to right,
      green 70%, 
      yellowgreen 70%, yellowgreen 80%, 
      yellow 80%, yellow 90%,
      salmon 90%
    );
```

To prevent the blurriness issue, all linear gradients in the example above define only 7 explicit gradient end-stops. (Note that the first linear gradient defines an 8th gradient stop, but not an explicit end-stop but just the start stop, as it isn't necessary to explicitly define the start-stop at the beginning or the end-stop at the end of the gradient (0% is automatically used as start-stop and 100% as end-stop), hence the blurriness bug isn't triggered.) The gradients above must use a transparent part to make the gradients below visible and still sharply end the gradient for the block-like visual.

[Codepen with bug and workaround demonstration.](https://codepen.io/strarsis/pen/MWbxWMw)

Related Chrome issues:

- https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1103863&q=gradient%20blurry&can=2
- https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1063769&q=gradient%20blurry&can=2
- https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=887971&q=gradient%20blurry&can=2
- https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=809999&q=gradient%20blurry&can=2

PostCSS plugin for automatically separating gradients with too many stops: https://github.com/strarsis/postcss-blurry-gradient-workaround

Note: The same issue also occurs with gradients as `border-image`. But `border-image` doesn't support multiple images or gradients compared to `background-image`.