# Chrome CSS linear gradient bug

Tags: css

I made some `linear-gradient` via [colorzilla](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) and it works fine, but in Chrome the border between the white and orange color is **"blurred"**. Is there a way to fix that?

Chrome:
[image]

FF: 
[image]

```css
html,
body,
div {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
div {
  background: #ffffff;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #ffffff 41%, #e38a2d 41%, #e38a2d 78%, #ffffff 78%, #ffffff 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #ffffff), color-stop(41%, #ffffff), color-stop(41%, #e38a2d), color-stop(78%, #e38a2d), color-stop(78%, #ffffff), color-stop(100%, #ffffff));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #ffffff 41%, #e38a2d 41%, #e38a2d 78%, #ffffff 78%, #ffffff 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #ffffff 41%, #e38a2d 41%, #e38a2d 78%, #ffffff 78%, #ffffff 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #ffffff 41%, #e38a2d 41%, #e38a2d 78%, #ffffff 78%, #ffffff 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 0%, #ffffff 41%, #e38a2d 41%, #e38a2d 78%, #ffffff 78%, #ffffff 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#ffffff', GradientType=0);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

---

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b56u6omf/)

Comment: it is just me that can't notice anything different, even in ScreenShots above?

Comment: @dippas open the images in a new tab and then switch one to the second and you'll notice the blurr.

Comment: run the snippet, the blur is more noticeable

Comment: possible duplicate of [Blurry linear gradient stops in chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26652661/blurry-linear-gradient-stops-in-chrome)