# CSS: Fuzzy linear gradient in Firefox

Tags: css, linear-gradients

A CSS linear gradient background element has fuzzy transitions between colours even when the stops are at the same spot.

I have an element with the background defined like so:

```
background:linear-gradient(to right,
    blue, blue 10%,
    red 10%, red 30%,
    yellow 30%, yellow 40%,
    green 40%, green 50%,
    black 50%
  );
```

In Firefox, the transitions between the colours are fuzzy.  If I use a `repeating-linear-gradient` the edges are crisp.  Both are crisp in Chrome.

I have an example pen here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rPVWZE?editors=1100#0

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: you want this particular gradient or in general?

Comment: Looks identical in Chrome and Firefox for me. All the edges are crisp

Comment: I can confirm the edges are a little blurry in Firefox 64.0.2. Even with px. Looks like someone nailed the rendering there.

Comment: Heres the fix for it :)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26652661/blurry-linear-gradient-stops-in-chrome

Comment: @Pilan I am also on FF 64.0.2 and the edges are perfectly sharp for me. Weird

Comment: @abney317 Take a screen and zoom in very close, you'll see 1px of each color marginly swapping over

Comment: @Pilan Yeah I did that. Definitely no blur on mine. https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6fe7.png

Answer (score 2):

Here the effect on FF. I drew some pixels to show zoom level:

[image]

A workaround:

```css
.linear{
  height:100px;
  
  background-image:
        linear-gradient(to right, blue 0, blue 100px),
        linear-gradient(to right, red 0, red 100px),
        linear-gradient(to right, yellow 0, yellow 100px);
  
  background-size:
        100px 100px,
        100px 100px,
        100px 100px;
  
  background-position:
        0 0,
        100px 0,
        200px 0;
  
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class = "linear"></div>
```

Comment: Your answer seems really complicated - but it does seem to be the only actual working solution.  I was hoping there was a flag or obscure css property that would allow the gradient to actually do what I told it to.  Thanks for the answer.